# WCF fails to deserialize JSON request

Tags: json, wcf

I'm trying to write a WCF service to respond to ajax requests, but I'm getting a strange error when it tries to deserialize.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'http://localhost:4385/Service.svc/MyMethod',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({folder:"test", name:"test"})
});
```

Here's the WCF service definition:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MyMethod", 
    Method = "*", //Need to accept POST and OPTIONS
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string[] MyMethod(string folder, string name);
```

I get a `SerializationException` saying: "The OperationFormatter could not deserialize any information from the Message because the Message is empty (IsEmpty = true)."

It occurs in method `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.PrimitiveOperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest` on instruction `00000108  mov         dword ptr [ebp-18h],0`

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, but it refuses to work for me.  Been fighting this all day.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it--the answer was staring right at me in the only comments in my code.  I needed to accept both POST and OPTIONS (for CORS).  The OPTIONS request was coming first, and of course the OPTIONS request comes with no data attached.  *That* was what was causing the parse exception; and the POST never even happened.

The workaround: separate out the POST and OPTIONS into two separate methods, with the same UriTemplate, but with different C# names (WCF requires this).

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MyMethod",
    Method = "POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string[] MyMethod(string folder, string name);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/MyMethod", Method = "OPTIONS")]
void MyMethodAllowCors();
```

That actually cleans up the code a bit because you don't have to litter all your functions with

```
if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method == "OPTIONS") {
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, POST");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, User-Agent");
    return new string[0];
} else if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method == "POST") { ... }
```